# Tirar uma foto com a Camera Frontal sem usar APIs obsoletas

Tags: android, android-camera

Estou desenvolvendo um app onde ao realizar o login, deve se tirar um foto!

Pesquisei a respeito e encontrei o seguinte [exemplo](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCamera/article.html) :

```
 public class PhotoHandler implements Camera.PictureCallback {

        private final Context context;

        public PhotoHandler(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            File pictureFileDir = getDir();

            if (!pictureFileDir.exists() && !pictureFileDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "Can't create directory to save image.");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Can't create directory to save image.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }


            String photoFile = "Picture_.jpg";
            String filename = pictureFileDir.getPath() + File.separator + photoFile;
            File pictureFile = new File(filename);
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();

            } catch (Exception error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Image could not be saved.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }
```

Ele utiliza o `android.hardware.Camera` que está deprecado!

Como posso realizar esta mesma ação utilizando o `android.graphics.Camera`?

Esta ação deve ser transparente ao Usuário.

Clicando no botão login, ele deve escolher a hora e automaticamente tirar a foto!

Comment: [android.graphics.Camera](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Camera.html) ou será [android.hardware.Camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)? Se for `android.hardware.Camera2` lembre que a aplicação só correrá em *Android* 5 ou superior.

Comment: Então, é pra versão  4.4 ! Não cheguei a testar a Camera2! Assim que possível testo e atualizo! Muito obrigado @ramaral

Comment: Se é para a 4.4 terá de usar *android.hardware.Camera*. O facto de ser considerada obsoleta apenas quer dizer que não deve ser utilizada quando é possível utilizar a que a substitui.

Comment: Então @ramaral, o problema é que não funciona! Implementei, e quando chamo o **takePicture**  não executa! Debugando, ele chama, mas não chama o **onPictureTaken**  Vou fazer mais alguns testes! Obrigado!

Comment: @ramaral não te esqueças de deixar uma resposta.

Answer (score 1):

voce pode usar a camera via intent , o codigo abaixo roda no 4.1 e no 6.0 , porem no 6.0 voce tera que adicionar a permission no run time (nao tive tempo de fazer ainda) mas voce pode ir no settins>app>NomeDoSeuApp>Permissions e adicionar a permision la .

```
public class CameraActivity extends Activity
{
    ImageView imageView;
    final int TAKE_PICTURE_CODE = 1;
    Uri outputFileUri;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_camera_activity);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    }
    /********** takePict **********/
    public void takePicture(View view)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),"myPicture.jpg");
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE,outputFileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_CODE);
    }
    /********** onActivityResult ********/
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(data==null) Log.d("TAG-DATA-RESULT","****** null ******");
        else
        {
            Bitmap picture = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
            imageView.setImageBitmap(picture);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas desta forma o usuário q vai tirar a foto?

Comment: Sim , voce que tira a foto sem que o usuario saiba ?

Comment: Isso... Quando entrar na tela ele tira a foto automáticamente sem ação do usuário

Comment: Meio complicado, porque nao tera como burlar o permission request

Comment: A permissão é de boa! Minha dúvida é mesmo como fazer isto por baixo

Comment: Foi mal ai entao , nao sabia que voce queria tirar a foto assim , acho que ai nesse caso voce tera que usar um if () else pra checa a version que esta rodando seu projeto

Comment: Oitra coisa q vc tera q fazer e checar se tem a front camera , alguns devices nao tem

Comment: Então, este projeto vai rodar em um aparelho específico! Obrigado pela ajuda!