# Como eu faço para salvar uma imagem em uma pasta recem criada pelo meu codigo?

Tags: android, android-camera

Estou com problemas na hora do armazenamento da minha foto, eu crio uma pasta usando o mkdir e através de uma string, pego o conteúdo de um EditText do meu aplicativo, para dar o nome da pasta.
Depois de inicializar a camera eu queria salvar a foto na mesma pasta criada, entao uso a mesma string para salva-la:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0){

        nome = nomeNovo.getText().toString();      

        File folder = new File("sdcard/" + nome);

        if (!folder.exists()){                
            pasta = folder.mkdir();            
        }             

        if (pasta == false){                
            linear.addView(teste);                
            }
        else {
            Intent intent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivity(intent);
        //    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Endereço: sdcard/" + nome , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            File arquivo = new File("sdcard/" + nome);
        }
```

O problema é que a foto continua sendo armazenada na pasta da câmera e não na pasta que eu criei.

Comment: OK, mas qual é o problema?

Comment: A foto esta sendo salva na pasta da camera, não na pasta que eu criei.

Comment: O código pra fazer isso é um pouco mais complicado. Dê uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/146539/uso-de-c%c3%a2mera-android) e no [exemplo oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html). Mas, basicamente, o problema é que você não está passando ao aplicativo que vai responder ao seu Intent a informação sobre o arquivo no qual a foto deve ser salva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue um exemplo para abrir a câmera e salvar com o nome que você quiser.

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/arquivo.jpg");
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Depois que você tirar a foto ele já vai salvar ela no caminho que vc passar no `new File()`

Comment: Estou tentando usar este código mas a foto não esta sendo salva, em lugar algum.
Alguma idéia ?

Comment: @LucasMoraesdeSouza, nesse caso a foto é salva na pasta "externa" do dispositivo (o que não é necessariamente uma mídia removível), este local pode mudar de APP para APP, aqui normalmente fica no `Armazenamento interno->Android->data->Sua pasta` para saber se ela está sendo salva ou não, faça um intent de view e passe essa mesma uri : `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(outputFileUri ), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);`

Comment: @LucasMoraesdeSouza, nesse meu exemplo, altere o trecho `/arquivo.jpg` para o caminho que você está usando, como o @LucasQueirozRibeiro disse, este caminho é da raíz do celular (sem considerar acesso root), é onde ficam as pastas de fotos, downloads, etc, para altere para `/minha_pasta/arquivo.jpg` e veja na pasta se está criando o arquivo.

Answer (score 0):

A rotina abaixo cria uma pasta dentro do diretório da app e salva as imagens dentro:

```
public void savarImagensToInternalStorage(String fileName, byte[] imagem){
        File dir = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/Imagens", fileName);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( dir );
            fos.flush();
            fos.write(imagem);
            fos.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("InternalStorage", "Error writing", e);
        }
    }
```